# How to suppress invalid function argument error?

Tags: php

If the function argument type is set and an argument of the wrong type is passed to this function, error is triggered. The problem is that this error is not suppressed by `@` operator. To be precise error message is muted but execution is stopped anyway.

```
function callback( DateTime $arg ) {
    return 'Success';
}

function doAction( callable $callback ) {    
    $value = 'Empty';
    $value = @$callback( 123 );
    var_dump( $value );   // Expect `Empty` or NULL here
}

doAction( 'callback' );
```

In PHP 7 this error can be caught by try-catch.

How to make this error not to stop execution on PHP 5.x.x?

Comment: You could always fix the error...

Comment: @JonStirling, the example is as simple as possible. the `test` function may vary, for example if it is a callback.

Comment: I don't think that changes my comment.

Comment: @JonStirling, what do you mean saying "fix the error"? Change the `test` function or change it's calling? It's not always possible.

Comment: Well if a function / method requires a certain type, then you make sure it is that type _before_ you pass it to said function / method.

Comment: @JonStirling This is on of possible solutions. How to do it?

Comment: Some quick research makes it sound like you can catch (and ignore if you want) these errors in supported versions of PHP by using a custom error handler. No I'm not going to explain how to do that.

Comment: Actually the code works fine, and the error is suppressed: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f60a55e68944ce2fe0d0c441d58557aa874571d8

Answer (score 0):

Set custom error handler that turns this error into an exception:

```
function callback( DateTime $arg ) {
    return 'Success';
}

function doAction( callable $callback ) {    
    $value = 'Empty';

    set_error_handler( function( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
        if ( $errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR )
            throw new ErrorException( $errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline );

        return false;
    });

    try {
        $value = @$callback( 123 );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {  // For PHP 5
    } catch ( Error $e ) {      // For PHP 7
    }

    restore_error_handler();

    var_dump( $value );   // Expect `Empty` or NULL here
}

doAction( 'callback' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Remove the type hinting and check the argument type in `callback` before operating with it. *(I would prefere this one)*
2. Check the value before passing it as argument and don't execute the callback.

***Note:*** using the error control operator is bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

You cane check whether passed in function is instance of DateTime class and throw error accordingly.

```
function test( DateTime $arg ) {
    if ($arg isinstanceof DateTime) {
        return 'Success';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument declaration will trigger an error before `instanceof` is executed.

Comment: The type operator is `instanceof`, not `isinstanceof`.